# When new members sign up an email gets sent to filter.select@gmail.com

Tags: civimember, email

We are using CiviCRM 4.6.4 in Wordpress.
We have a membership page processed through paypal.
All emails are sending from our own SMTP server.

However, when an email is sent as acknowledgement of signup/payment
for membership, there is also an email being sent to filter.select@gmail.com

What is this email and how do I stop it from being sent?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you some kind of customization that sends out those emails, I can only think of one place should have a look at:

1. go to "Contributions" --> "Manage Contribution Pages"
2. next to the contribution page in question, use the link "configure" and then "Thank-You and receipting"
3. tick the box "Email Receipt to Contributor" (if not ticked already) and check if "filter.select@gmail.com" is in the cc or bcc field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, there's no email going to filter.select@gmail.com there (only one to our donation email address).  Also I notice something strange, the email sent to filter.select@gmail.com is not an exact copy of the signup email, it lacks the name of the new member.

Comment: Hmm if nothing is there or at the scheduled reminders of your event and if you are not using any extensions or customizations I really don't know where this comes from - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be if you have a profile in use on the membership page which has a setting to notify someone when that profile is filled out. Go to **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles** and click "Settings" on the profile in question, in the *Advanced Settings* section look for "Notify when profile form is submitted":

[image: Profile Advanced Settings]